# Led lights in parallel to 220v

Tags: led, resistors, parallel, series

I want to start a project with led lights, but I am completely new to working with electricity (i have used electricity but have never created something myself).

I want to create a led wire with different leds connected to 220v. I know that the different colors of leds use a different voltage, so my plan was to wire each color in parallel, and for example, all reds will be in series.

Is this the right way to do it? Or does someone has a better recommendation? What will I need to convert the 220v to the right voltage? and what other materials do i need?

Comment: "I want to create a led wire with different leds connected to 220v." Not if you're new to electricity. Get used to low voltages (<30V) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good idea.

220 V is lethal. To do this project would require you to perform voltage and current measurements on live wiring and given your lack of experience this would be strongly discouraged. You should try this on low voltage circuits.

A simple transformer to step the voltage from mains to, say, 24 V AC would provide you with a safe working voltage adequate to try out your ideas.

> I want to create an LED wire with different LEDs connected to 220 V. I know that the different colors of LEDs use a different voltage, so my plan was to wire each color in parallel, and for example, all reds will be in series.

LEDs are current sensitive so if you don't need colour switching the standard practice is to wire all LEDs requiring the same current in series. The supply then requires some sort of current limiting circuit.

Your other concern is that LEDs are DC devices and you are proposing to run on AC. You need to figure out how to prevent destruction of the LEDs on the negative half-cycle.

There are millions of articles on LEDs. Read, read, read and stay away from mains.

Comment: The only problem is that I need to wire around 20-30 lights. I don't think that is possible on a 9V battery.

Comment: Or buy three off the shelf LED drivers. They are not expensive. Or one intended for more than one string.STill..be careful, the voltages will be up there.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  A better way is to use some Mean Well Constant Current Drivers.
Use a 36v (e.g LPV-35-36 or APV-35-36) constant Voltage to power multiple LDD-xxx modules. The LDD modules have a minimum of 300mA and max of 20-30 LEDs per string depending on color and forward voltages.

This is a very simple way to provide the requisite constant current to the LEDs.

[image]

The diagram is from the On-Semi datasheet for their [NSI45090JDT4G Adjustable Constant Current Regulator & LED Driver](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NSI45090JD-D.PDF)

Other CCRs: 
[Diodes Inc, AL5808 60V Two Terminal Constant Current LED Driver](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL5809.pdf)

[Microchip MIC4801, High Efficiency 600mA Single Channel 
Linear LED Driver](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en579355)

LINK: [On-Semi NSI450xx EVAL BOARD SCHEMATIC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CCRGEVB_SCHEMATIC.PDF)

Comment: Note: **The ON-Semiconductor diagram is a badly drawn kind of block diagram. It is not a full schematic and will not work as drawn.** (For example, the AC supply is shown as two wires connected to the one point. They should be connected to the top and bottom of the bridge and the LED negative returned to the left end of the bridge.) Anyone thinking of using these devices should read and understand their application notes. (The diagram is ON's and not Misunderstood's.)

Comment: @Transistor I added a link to the Eval Board schematic.